# IOS/Objective-C: Syntax for calling completion bloc

Tags: objective-c, completionhandler

For some reason, I cannot seem to get the following call right.

The method signature is:

```
-(void)getMyBlock: (void (^)(NSString *))completed; // It returns a string.
```

The following attempt (and about ten others I have tried) to call it is not working:

```
[self getMyBlock: (void (^)(NSString*)completed];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how your block method should be:

```
-(void)getMyBlock: (void (^)(NSString * yourString))completed {
    completed(@"HELLO");
}
```

And this is how you call it:

```
[self getMyBlock:^(NSString *yourString) {
    NSLog(@"%@", yourString);
}];
```

This link would help you out:
http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: I certainly hope the implementation of `getMyBlock` is doing a lot more than that, otherwise there is no need for the completion block.

Comment: It is doing a lot more--several layers of methods and server calls, but the completed(result) syntax was the issue that at the end was confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a block for the `completed` parameter:

```
[self getMyBlock:^(NSString *result) {
    // this code is called when the asynchronous code inside getMyBlock is done
}];
```

Somewhere in the implementation of the `getMyBlock` method is code along the lines of:

```
- (void)getMyBlock: (void (^)(NSString *))completed {
    // do some asynchronous stuff
    NSString *result = // some result string
    if (completed) {
        completed(result);
    }
}
```